# Is there a way to programatically extract all record IDs from a filtered (server-side) datatables recordset?

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10, yadcf

Using datatables in server-side mode, with YADCL for filtering, is there any way that I can programatically extract the record IDs (e.g. 
column 0 contains those IDs) for the entire filtered recordset (not just the paginated results shown) such that I can then carry out an action on that recordset.

Example: a 'customers' database table contains 80k records and I use YADCF filtering to narrow that down to a recordset of 1k customers, 20 of which are displayed on the web-page. I would like to have a button on the page, labeled 'Mark all filtered records', that when clicked, fires off an ajax script that changes the 'mark' field on the filtered 1,000 records from 0 to 1.

I can handle the marking of the records independently of datatables, but I don't know how to programatically work out which records need marking i.e. I need to extract some form of recordset identification that I can then use to target with my SQL UPDATE action. Any ideas anyone?

Comment: have you added some yadcf related code on your server side? yadcf_data_0 / yadcf_data_1 / etc  ? like specified on showcase http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html

Comment: Yes I have Daniel, but unless I'm missing something, I can't see what that has to do with my question. I've come up with a workaround by capturing, parsing and sanitising the SQL query used during filtering (in the SSP), storing it as a session var, then using it during the 'mark' action, but it took a lot of work and I'm still curious to know if there's a simpler way to extract the unpaginated, filtered recordset. I don't need the record IDs as such, but I do need to know which records belonged to the recordset. By capturing the SQL query's WHERE elements, I have achieved a working solution.

Comment: it sounds like that your question is not related to yadcf filtering behavior

Comment: It is, because yadcf is doing the filtering of a table to produce a filtered recordset. It then displays that recordset in paginated form. My question is, can that entire filtered recordset be extracted or referenced programatically such that one can carry out an UPDATE action on that entire filtered recordset? If the answer is no, then fair enough (I've created a workaround), but that is my question, thanks :)

Comment: I think you are confusing between the purpose of yadcf and datatables, yadcf is allowing you to filter easily your datatable, e.g. it triggers /send the setting of  columns[0][search][value] with relevant values, then your server code is responsible for getting the relevant rows from db and sending them back to client / datatables

Comment: OK, fair enough, thanks Daniel. Everything I do server-side is heavily extended from an example SSP script from github, and the boundary lines between datatables, yadcf and that SSP are a little blurred in my mind. That said, I have tagged this question for both datatables and yadcf, and was looking for any help from any quarter. So in summary then, the functionality that I seek is down to me to add, which I have since done anyway, and it works fine. Thanks for taking the time to respond, and thanks again for YADCF, which has become an important core component of my latest business app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similiar problem, here's what I did:

- added a hidden input-field
- used the drawCallback-option of Datatables to trigger a function that wrote the ids of all active (filtered) records to that input-field
- on callbacks to the server, included the content of that input-field

The tricky detail was the drawCallback-function:

```
function (settings) {                                                              
dtObj = this.api();                                                                
var dtData = dtObj.column(0,{ search: 'applied', selected: true }).data().toArray();   
$("#dtdata").val(JSON.stringify(dtData));                                          
}
```

- the first argument of that `column`-call is the index of the column you're interested in (0 has my index)
- that 2nd argument selects all rows that matched search/filter-criteria. They also work with yadcf-filtering!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and detail, but I was after the IDs for the entire filtered recordset, not just the paginated results shown. As I subsequently explained, it was not the IDs I needed per see, but to be able to reproduce the filtered recordset in its entirety, so that I could act on that recordset. I've come up with a workaround by capturing, parsing and sanitising the SQL query used during filtering (in the SSP), storing it as a session var, then using it in a subsequent action that doesn't involved datatables.

Comment: Ok, glad you got it working.  But just for the record: my suggestion returns all IDs of records in the table, not restricted by pagination.

Comment: I'm sorry MBaas, but because you said: "...that wrote the ids of all shown records..." and the DT docs example says: "...output the data for the visible rows...", I thought you'd misunderstood my question. In that case, even though I have solved my problem by other means, I will accept your answer, with apologies.

Comment: Thanks. I see my reply was misleading and changed the wording.